# How to Access Image in local JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, react-native-swiper

```
Hijama = [
{
  name: 'Body Back',
  pic: '../Images/BackSide.png',
},
{
  name: 'Body Front',
  pic: '../Images/images.jpg',
},];
```

//here i want to render my pics

```
     render_swiper_data = () => {
return this.Hijama.map((item, index) => {
  console.log('check', item);
  return (
    <View key={index}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      <Image
        source={require(item.pic)}
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
})};
```

//now my question is how can i access these images i try both Require and uri,,,

Comment: It looks right, do you get a error? or is it just that the img path is wrong?

Comment: use src={require(item.pic)} not source={require(item.pic)} because you are requiring a local image, not a url image.

Comment: @P4uB0rd4 in react native you are suposed to use source like this `<Image source={require('./assets/image.png')} />` If you are using react-natives Image component that is

Comment: This looks correct. I couldn't reproduce. See: https://snack.expo.io/B1mJ1OJPr The only thoughts I have are maybe your image paths are wrong, or your render method isn't getting called. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Patte yes an error occur like this "Invalid call at line 31: require(JSON.stringify(item.pic))"

Comment: @MajidAziz Why are you stringifying item.pic? It's already a string.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie i also try this but it not working

Comment: @MajidAziz "Not working" is not a helpful problem description. Are you getting any errors without JSON.stringify? Have you looked at the link I posted with the working example?

Comment: @AndroidNoobie i got texts only not Images in a Swiper

Comment: @AndroidNoobie i check this link working correctly but in Swiper Images doesnot render

Comment: @AndroidNoobie you are using images from another Location while i m getting images from local docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot using require like that. react-native can't read it.
so you must store all of local image location like this:

```
Hijama = [
{
  name: 'Body Back',
  pic: require('../Images/images.jpg'),
},
{
  name: 'Body Front',
  pic: require('../Images/images2.jpg')
},];
```

and then use it in your code:

```
     render_swiper_data = () => {
return this.Hijama.map((item, index) => {
  console.log('check', item);
  return (
    <View key={index}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      <Image
        source={item.pic}
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
})};
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is some constants in all images you can use template literals.

```
src={require(`./Images/${image}.png`)}
```

And make `${image}` inside your Hijama's loop.

p.s. I recommend you to refactor your variable names (use camelCase)